# How to JqGrid EDIT form make responsive

Tags: javascript, css, jqgrid

I am working on one project in that using JqGrid but remaining all project elements are responsive. but only JqGrid edit form and Add form are not responsive how to make edit and add forms of JqGrid responsive.

Please give suggetion.

Comment: Have you hab any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a URL for this?
If you look at the code and the "Edit Form" and "Add Form" have a class or id. Or even if they are inside a container div, and this div has a class or id, you can manipulate CSS to make it responsive.

Comment: If you have 3 column in 1 row ex: formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 1 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 2 }, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 3 }. It will fail?